# Object of class mysqli could not be converted to string

Tags: php, mysqli

I had my old website so I've decided to change it from mysql_ to mysqli so I've managed to complete 40% and now i am stuck with this problem.Help Me!

I am getting error on 'implode()' function

```
function user_data($user_id,$conn){
$data = array();
$user_id = (int)$user_id;

$func_num_args = func_num_args();
$func_get_args = func_get_args();

if ($func_num_args > 1){

    unset($func_get_args[0]);
    $fields = '`'.implode('`,`',$func_get_args).'`';
    $query = "SELECT ".$fields." FROM users WHERE user_id = ".$user_id."";
    $result = mysqli_query($conn,$query) or die(mysqli_error($conn));
    while ($row = $result->fetch_assoc()) {
    $data = $row['user_id'];
    }

    return $data;
    }
}
```

In order to get below code to work properly

```
if (logged_in() === true){
$session_user_id = $_SESSION['user_id'];
$user_data = user_data($session_user_id,'user_id','username',
            'password','first_name','last_name','email','type',$conn);
}
```

Any alternate way to perform same task will

Comment: what error you get ??

Comment: Catchable fatal error: Object of class mysqli could not be converted to string

Comment: please see error o which line it throws and point that line here ... Not the function name,

Comment: 8th line  $fields = '`'.implode('`,`',$func_get_args).'`';

Comment: this code looks unsafe to use in a live environment

Answer (score -1, accepted):

You have not correct definition of `user_data` function,

In it's signature you have only **two** arguments:

```
function user_data($user_id, $conn)
```

So, these arguments are `$user_id` and `$conn`.

But when you call your `user_data` you pass **more** than 2 arguments:

```
user_data($session_user_id,'user_id','username', 'password','first_name','last_name','email','type',$conn);
```

See, you have **8** arguments here. And `$conn` is not the second one, it's eighth!

And when you do

```
$fields = '`'.implode('`,`',$func_get_args).'`';
```

last argument which holds your mysqli-connection is being added to `$fields`.

So, you have to rewrite your function, for example this way:

```
function user_data($user_id, $conn, $fields) {
    $data = array();
    $user_id = (int)$user_id;

    $fields = '`'.implode('`,`', $fields).'`';
    $query = "SELECT ".$fields." FROM users WHERE user_id = ".$user_id."";
    $result = mysqli_query($conn, $query) or die(mysqli_error($conn));
    while ($row = $result->fetch_assoc()) {
        $data = $row['user_id'];
    }

    return $data;
}
```

And call it for example:

```
$user_data = user_data(
    $session_user_id,   // $user_id
    $conn,              // $conn
    array('user_id','username','password','first_name','last_name','email','type')    // fields as ARRAY
);
```

Answer (score -1):

$func_get_args has $user_id, other string values and at last the mysqli connection object. You must unset last element of function parameters. Correct user_data function is that:

```
function user_data($user_id,$conn){
$data = array();
$user_id = (int)$user_id;

$func_num_args = func_num_args();
$func_get_args = func_get_args();

if ($func_num_args > 1){

    unset($func_get_args[0]);
    unset($func_get_args[ $func_num_args - 1]); // you must delete last element becouse this is mysqli object
    $fields = '`'.implode('`,`',$func_get_args).'`';
    $query = "SELECT ".$fields." FROM users WHERE user_id = ".$user_id."";
    $result = mysqli_query($conn,$query) or die(mysqli_error($conn));
    while ($row = $result->fetch_assoc()) {
    $data = $row['user_id'];
    }

    return $data;
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks bro , you made my day